# How do I separate react js cards?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6, frontend

[I want to separate them and line up horizontally and vertically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXXut.jpg)

```
    import React from 'react'
import "./Projects.css";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


function Projects({projectsData}) {
    return (
      <>
       {projectsData.map((index)=>{
           const{img,link,title}=index
           return(
            <div className="_div_">
              <div className="cards_">
              <div className="_imag">
                    <img src={img}/>
                    <div className="_writings">
                        <h1>{title}</h1>
                        <a href={link}> See Project</a>
                    </div>
                    

                </div>
              </div>

               
           </div>
           )
       })}
      </>
    )
}

export default Projects

._div_{
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    /* To adjust the height as well */
    height: fit-content;
 
    }

._imag{
    height: auto;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: rgb(183, 183, 204);
    border-radius: 9px;

}
._imag img{
    margin-top:0px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

._writings{
    height: 40%;
    
}
.cards_{
    display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: center;
}

import React from 'react'
import BodySection from "../Navbar/BodySection"
import Navbar from "../Navbar/Navbar"
import Content from "../Navbar/Content"
import {Data1,projectsData} from "./Data"
import Projects from "../Navbar/Projects"

function Home() {
    return (
        <>
          <BodySection/>  
          <Content{...Data1}/>
          <Projects projectsData={projectsData}/>

        </>
    )
}

export default Home
```

I want to separate the cards and put them horizontally and vertically and not just vertically.
thank you.
Please ignore what I am about to write because it wont let me post this saying I need to add more details but I dont have more details to add.

Comment: Use flexbox or grid layout.

Comment: flexbox is not working and if I am doing wrong I dont know what to do to do it right. I've been trying for hours.

Comment: Can you make a working example on codesandbox?

Comment: Its not supposed to be like this but it became like this anyway. It was supposed to be like in the photo.
https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-sun-nf1b3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top level should be the flex into which you map the cards, something like this:

```
function Projects({ projectsData }) {
  return (
    <div className="_div_">
       <div className="cards_">
      {projectsData.map((index) => {
        const { img, link, title } = index;
        return (
              <div className="_imag">
                <img src={img} />
                <div className="_writings">
                  <h1>{title}</h1>
                  <a href={link}> See Project</a>
                </div>
              </div>
        );
      })}
      </div>
   </div>
  );
}
```

You should probably have a card element together with these properties on `cards_` to position them better:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap

Comment: Thank you million times. As a self learner with VERY limited time and with no background, it hurts to get stuck on simple stuff despite wasting million hours on it.

Comment: @Roshan no problem, if it helped you mark this as the answer

Answer (score -1):

This is a perfect use case for css flexbox. I threw together a quick [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-carson-bp77g?file=/src/App.js:138-186) for you.

You can use my code as a starting point and expand out to your use case.

If you need a quick intro to flexbox here's a great [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K74l26pE4YA).

Comment: The thing is I know basic flexbox. I have problem when react and css mix just like in this case.

Comment: You need to map your "cards" into a parent div with the `display: flex`. Currently you're not doing that. You have `display: flex` on the cards, which probably isn't necessary or what you're going for.